# Probability of three Independent events(A,B,C)

Tags: probability

Kindly help with this question. Can't seem to find the answer.
Let A,B,C be events such that A and B are independent.A and C are independent.A and BnC are independent
Show that A and BnC are independent.
Thanks

Comment: You say:  A and BnC are independent Show that A and BnC are independent. Thanks.   This must be a typo!